# Any downside to using a view to make sure stored procedures get all the columns they need?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me start by stating that when writing `SELECT` statements in a stored procedure or elsewhere in application code, I ALWAYS specify columns explicitly rather than using `SELECT *`.

That said, I have a case where I have many stored procedures that need exactly the same columns back because they are used to hydrate the same models on the client.  In an effort to make the code less brittle and less prone forgetting to update a stored procedure with a new column, I am thinking of creating a view and selecting from that in my stored procedures using `SELECT *`.

To help clarify, here are examples of what the stored procedures might be named:

```
   Entity_GetById
   Entity_GetByX
   Entity_GetForY
   -- and on and on...
```

So in each of these stored procedures, I would have

```
SELECT * 
FROM EntityView 
WHERE...[criteria based on the stored procedure]
```

I'm wondering if there is any cost to doing this. I understand the pitfalls of `SELECT * FROM Table` but by selecting from a view that exists specifically to define the columns needed seems to mitigate this.

Are there any other reasons I wouldn't want to use this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see a problem with this approach.

However, there is a range of opinions on the use of `select *` in production code, which generally discourages it for the outermost query (of course, it is fine in subqueries).

You do want to make sure that the stored procedures are recompiled if there is any change to either the view or to the underlying tables supplying the view.  You probably want to use [schemabinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to ensure that (some) changes to the underlying tables do not inadvertently affect the view(s).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your system, but using a view would not affect performance?

`SELECT *` from the view makes sense, but does the view just selects specific columns from one table?

If not then look carefully into performance.

If I remember correctly in MS SQL stored procedure can return a recordset.
If I right you can try to wrap various queries into kind of sub queries stored procedure and have a one main which selects specific columns -- here complication should fail if you miss something in .

Even better would be having stored procedures which ask by various parameters and returns only primary keys (as record set or in temporary table) and one main which fetch all required columns based on returned primary keys.

Comment: Your last proposal might make the most sense.  One thing I didn't initially think about with the view approach is that the view won't contain all the columns I need to query against.